# Python source analyzer that works with zope components

Tags: python, code-analysis, python-2.6, zope, zope.interface

There's a code base (Py 2.6 stuff) that extensively uses zope components and there's a need for tool that can analyze the sources. The tool is supposed to analyze the source; like look for usage of some restricted classes/objects/interfaces, etc. Basically, scan each statement in the source while being aware of the statement's context (which class/method/function it is in, which module, etc) and analyze it for specific patterns.

The approach of reading the source into text buffers and matching patterns doesn't seem to be a reliable approach at all.

Another approach that came up was of using *inspect*, but *inspect* [seems to be broken](http://bugs.python.org/issue1785) and doesn't seem to be able to handle our code base (multiple tries, all of them crashed inspect). I might have to give up on that as there seems to be now way out with *inspect*.

Now, other options that I could think of are using *pylint* or using *AST* (and doing a lot of postprocessing on it). Am not sure to what extent *pylint* is extensible; and when it comes to analyzing source statments if pylint could be aware of context (i.e, which class defn/function/method has this statement etc) Using *AST* seems too much of an overkill for such a trivial purpose.

What would you suggest as a suitable approach here? Anybody else had to deal with such an issue before?

Please suggest.